# Umbraco upgrade - media types disappeared

Tags: umbraco

**Media Types disapeared from Settings after upgrade from 7.2.8 to 7.4.3**

Wish I was doing a tutorial instead of asking for help... but I have no idea what to do.

I finally was able to upgrade... Didn't go smoothly but easier than trying to 7.3.0.

The only errors that I got where regarding the database... (duplicate id entry). I was able to work around that.

It finished with a notification of an error and to check the log... there weren't any errors in the log so not sure about that.

So the site is working... I even used one of my Media Types to change out Banners and no problems... BUT my Media Types are missing under the settings -> Media Types section.

*Here is what my Media Types looked like:*

> [image: Before Upgrade]

*Here is what I now have:*

> [image: After Upgrade]

I thought maybe that it was consolidated into some sort of Composition but nothing...

> [image]

The only thing I can think to do, and have started, is to go through all of the changes from 7.2.8 to 7.4.3. That is over a week's worth of reading... time I don't have with my workload.

Even if I find a change, I probably won't know how to fix it (expeditiously). Any  one know how to fix this breaking change?

Comment: Seen as only Media types that are inherited from others are missing, could you try creating a new media type inherited from one of the available types. I do not have a site I can test on but it may be possible that the inheritance feature isn't working/was removed. Also could you check the definition of the types in the DB as you mentioned an ID issue, perhaps during the upgrade the `ParentId` has been lost on the child types.

Comment: Thanks @Anth12... I did try to create a media type that inherits from the folder media type. The system won't let me do it that way now.  I believe it needs to be done using "composites" without the ability to nest the types in the tree. I will be looking further into the DB to try and find a broken ParentId issue.

Comment: There is no change in the database. All the relationships are still there. I wonder if the code changed. Not Good!